# HTML child appearing behind parent

Tags: html, css, parent-child, materialize

I am by no means good at coding HTML or CSS, but through no choice of my own I have been forced to design a website.  The actual functionality of the site can be limited, just so long as it looks like it works.

I have been allowed to use Materialize for effects and formatting (and whatever else it's good at).  This is probably where the problem has arisen from.  I have chosen to use a [carousel](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) from Materialize to display items on a page to "show my capabilities" and all that.  The fact that this question exists may be contradictory to that.

The implementation of this went better than I expected, however, I wish to put text over said image in the carousel.  Each image will have different text.  I want the text to be inside a dark translucent box to create a shadow effect and to make the text readable.  I have the following code:

```
.background {
height: calc(100% - 64px);
width: 100%;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-wrapper {
position: relative;
top: 5%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
max-height: 70vh;
max-width: 70vw;
}
.shadow-box {
position: absolute;
width: 55vw;
height: 55vh;
background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
z-index: 500 !important;
}
<div class="background">
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" style="z-index: 250 !important;" data-indicators="true">
            <div class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="Tree_ropes.jpg">
                <div class="shadow-box">
                    <h2 style="font-weight: bold">Tree Ropes</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The thing is, *shadow-box* ought to appear on top of it's parent *carousel-item one*, right?  This is not the case.  When I load up the page (on Microsoft Edge) *shadow-box* appears behind it's parent (you have to delete the picture element in the F12 menu to see it).

Comment: try giving a higher z-index that what the image has if that does not work try sharing all your code css included

Comment: @ClaudiuD. I have tried changing the z-index of both elements to no avail.  I will edit and add the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: be careful that z-index works only on positioned elements

Comment: @ClaudiuD. Is that enough info for you?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give it a try with this

```css
.background {
height: calc(100% - 64px);
width: 100%;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;

}
.carousel-wrapper {
position: relative;
top: 5%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
max-height: 70vh;
max-width: 70vw;
}
.shadow-box {
position: absolute;
width: 55vw;
height: 55vh;
background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
z-index: 500 !important;
}
.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-item .shadow-box {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" style="z-index: 250 !important;" data-indicators="true">
            <div class="carousel-item" href="#one!">
              <img src="https://thehealthyhive.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/linden-tree.jpg">
              <div class="shadow-box">
                <h2 style="font-weight: bold">Tree Ropes</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will give that a try.  Is _.carousel-item_ supposed to be there with _.shadow-box_?

Comment: that's how you define that .shadow-box is a child of .carousel-item so yes it suppose to be there

Comment: This does appear to have done the trick!  Please ignore my last comment; I have run out of coffee.  Thank you.

Comment: ha ha been there :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a div in the wrong spot.

Try this:

```
<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="Tree_ropes.jpg"></a>
<div class="shadow-box">
    <h2 style="font-weight: bold">Tree Ropes</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you post the rest of the code (CSS) or codepen link? Need to know what you are trying to do with .shadow-box.

Comment: _shadow-box_ is just a simple rectangle with text in it used to create a shadow above (supposedly) the image.  Using an <a> tag has the same effect as using a <div>.

Comment: Add position: relative; to shadow-box

Comment: Instead of being layered, they are now below one another, which I suppose is an improvement.  The reason I was using a <div> was to ensure that each _shadow-box_ appeared over the correct image as a child of that image in the carousel.

Comment: the boxes are on top now which is a bonus